# How can I check if a Lit or Web Component element has connected/mounted from another component, as well as listen to when it does?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, lit

Assuming an HTML structure with 2 custom web components `<my-component-one>` and `<my-component-two>` using lit that are individually lazy loaded, is it somehow possible to check within one of the components to see if the other has already loaded/rendered/mounted?

So far, my only success is relying on the `shadowRoot` property, as well as emitting a `CustomEvent` from the other component's `connectedCallback` and listening to it;

```js
@customElement('my-component-one')
export class MyComponentOne extends LitElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback()
    if (document.querySelector('my-component-two')?.shadowRoot) {
      console.log(' component two mounted, it loaded before component one')
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('my-component-two:mounted', () => {
        console.log(' component two mounted, it loaded after component one')
      })
    }
  }
}

// somewhere within my-component-two's connectedCallback()
this.dispatchEvent('my-component-two:mounted', {
  bubbles: true,
  composed: true
})
```

Curious if there is a simpler way to achieve this? It would be fantastic if I didn't have to emit a custom event within the other component. I tried variations of `document.querySelector('my-component-two').addEventListener('connectedCallback')` by trying all lifecycle events as well as verbs like `mounted`, `ready`, `load|loaded` and `idle` but nothing seems to be natively emitted as far as events I can intercept when lit/web components are loaded.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: No, not without extra code like you created. Components are just HTML elements, one DIV will not be notified when another DIV is placed in the DOM either. Which gets you an alternative solution... you can try the Mutation Observer API

Comment: Could you elaborate on the Mutation Observer part?

Comment: Read the fine manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver